# Why my Web custom font is not being applied?

Tags: html, css

I have a custom font in my Web site, and I uploaded it to my site.

[This](http://ginsandtonics.es/) is my site.

I want to apply all my Web the `oswaldlight`. Since now, I've uploaded the font into a known folder for me and added it as a `@font-face` like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'oswaldlight';
src: url('../font/oswald/oswald.light-webfont.eot');
src: url('../font/oswald/oswald.light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/oswald/oswald.light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../font/oswald/oswald.light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/oswald/oswald.light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../font/oswald/oswald.light-webfont.svg#oswaldlight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

This piece of code has been added in my ftp. And if you check which font is using each heading, you see this using Firebug:

```
element.style {
   color: #000000;
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weight: normal;
   line-height: 40px;
   margin: 12px 0 0;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: left;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
*::before, *::after {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
 *::before, *::after {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.heading h2 {
   font-family: "oswaldlight";
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weight: normal;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

But it's still not being applied to my heading. Any idea why it's not being applied?

**EDIT:** I saw the error that @Lucky Chingi mentions. I added to my `.htcaccess` the following lines:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

Header add (also tried 'set') Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

# END WordPress
```

But it still doesn't work... Any suggestions?

Comment: does console shows any 404 errors? Besides- .woff has so broad support that I don't see a sense to attach any other extensions other than woff.

Comment: It looks like your file path may be off, using `../` to go up a level is relative to where your css file is stored.

Comment: Font from origin 'http://smolinaperez.nom.es' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ginsandtonics.es' is therefore not allowed access. - on Chrome Dev console

Comment: 1. No any 404 error shown...
2. Yes, I now. It's relative to the path where the css is stored... but actually the font is there!
3. How you know about smolinaperez.nom.es? That's the old site and I don't know how did you get there...

Comment: Check your config files to see if your old website isn't loaded somewhere

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to load the fonts from an external URL and you are getting a cross-origin error. You should host the fonts, css files and other assets on the same server as the rest of the website.

Comment: Okay, I explain exactly. Today I made a domain transfer to a new Web hosting. So everything is supposed to be hosted by my new Web hosting. But I would like to note that everything is located again in the new Web hosting.

Comment: It's not though. You are calling your CSS and font files from  smolinaperez.nom.es. Host the CSS files and the other assets on ginsandtonics.es, use relative paths and it will work.

Comment: I see that you added Google Fonts but you didn't change your Font Family. I updated my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a problem with my Web domain that was pointing to another private domain. After a while, it ended pointing to my destiny domain. Thanks boys!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to host your fonts on your page. Google delivers fonts fast.

So you can do:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
```

This imports the font as 'Oswald' using `@font-face`. If you type the above URL into the browser, you also see that it dynamically loads different files depending on which browser you're using. Try on Firefox and on Chrome to see for yourself.

Now wherever you want Oswald, simply type:

```
font-family: Oswald;
```

Also, for best results, **load your font-faces before loading any other CSS**.

Answer (score -1):

try

`*{font:100%/1.0 'oswaldlight';}`

make sure your path to that font-file(s) are correct
and, remove headers if possible, some browsers behave differently with some headers